# How to send a variable from PHP to Adobe Animate?

Tags: php, html, variables, jquery-animate, adobe

I'm making `HTML5/Canvas` banner with dynamic text field using `Adobe Animate`.

How to send a variable from `PHP` or `Javascript` to `Adobe Animate`?

Previously I used `FlashVars`, but how to do it in `HTML5/Canvas`?